# Search large CSV files with multiple search criteria on unix

Tags: perl, file, search, csv

I have several large CSV files that I need to search with 1 to many parameters, if I find  a hit I need to save that line in another file.  Below is an example of perl code that runs successfully but is very slow against a 5gb file.  Any suggestions on speeding this up would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Text::CSV_XS;

$numArgs = $#ARGV;

#First Parameter is the input file name
$Finput = $ARGV[0];
chomp($Finput);

#Second Parameter is the output file name
$Foutput = $ARGV[1];
chomp($Foutput);

# Open the Control file but quit if it doesn't exist
open(INPUT1, $Finput) or die "The Input File $Finput could not be found.\n";
open(OUTPUT1, ">$Foutput") or die "Cannot open output $Foutout file.\n";


my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new();
open my $FH, "<", $Finput;

while (<$FH>) {
    $csv->parse($_);
    my @fields = $csv->fields;

    if ($fields[0] == 10000) {
        if ($fields[34] eq 'abcdef') {
            if ($fields[103] == 9999) {
                print OUTPUT1 "$_\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if( $fields[0] = 10000)`... and `if( $fields[34] = 'abcdef' )` are probably not doing what you think.  You probably want the `==` operator (for numeric comparisons) and the `eq` operator for string comparison.  It's hard to imagine this code actually worked correctly the way it's posted.

Comment: You're also never reading from `INPUT1` in your example code.  For a truly accurate answer we would need to know what your existing (working) algorithm looks like, or what your input and output data should look like.  Since the code posted can't be an accurate representation of what you're actually successfully but slowly running, we can only guess what you really need.

Comment: Thanks DavidO...I corrected the operators and I do accept 2 parameters when I call this script, so I run it like this...perl script.pl

Comment: continued thought...so I run it like this...perl script.pl input_file.csv out_putfile.csv...this does read in the first file and loops through it and produces the second file if found. The input date is like this..(20110718043719,10000,"NAME, Association",1110101,,I,1,1,USA,USA.....new line then another row 20110718043719,10000,"NAME, Association",1110101,,I,1,1,USA,USA).  If a match is found then we should copy that entire line to the new file.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know your data, or your criteria.

But if we could use your example given above, then I would try trivial tests against the lines BEFORE doing the CSV handling.

For example (note, my perl is terrible, this is meant to be exemplar, not correct):

```
if (/.*10000.*abcdef.*9999.*/) {
    $csv->parse($_);
    if ($fields[0] = 10000) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Basically, you do some simpler, faster checks to more quickly DISQUALIFY rows before performing the additional processing necessary to qualify them.

Clearly if more of your rows match than do not, or if the check for simple qualification isn't really practical, then this technique won't work.

Done right, CSV parsing is a bit expensive (in fact you have a error here assuming that a single line of CSV is a single record, that may be true for your data, but CSV actually allows embedded newlines, so it's not a generic assumption that can be made for all CSV).

So, it's good to not have to pay the price of parsing it if, "at a glance", the line isn't going to match anyway.

Comment: I see your point on the pre-validation before parsing, let me give that a try and see if it saves some time.

Comment: I doubt that performing a regex search on a line with hundreds of fields will be faster than what's inside that if.

Comment: Combined, the overall process will likely be slower per line, but the basic premise is that there are more false lines than true lines, so overall its faster. There's nothing that says you have to check for all of the fields, a simple test for 10000 perhaps would be enough to reject a majority of lines. Regex in perl is written in C and quite fast, I don't know was the CSV module is written in, but it's likely in Perl itself. The CSV module will necessarily create a lot of data (the fields for example) that won't be needed if in fact the line is rejected.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion *if* there's no possibility of a `\n` embedded within a field.  But the regexp would be more efficient broken up into three smaller matches.  Example: `if( /\D10000\D/ and /\babcdef\b/ and /\D9999\D/ ) { $csv->parse($_); ....`.  The goal is three small easy to match regexps that will never have any backtracking complexity.  It really shouldn't matter if the regexps don't check for field order.  The goal is just to reject a large percentage of "not possible" lines, and leave the additional checking for a small subset of rows.

Answer (score 2):

This is code that runs "successfully"? I find that hard to believe.

```
if ($fields[0] = 10000) {
    if ($fields[34] = 'abcdef') {
        if ($fields[103] = 9999) {
```

These are not checks for equality, but assignments. All of these if-clauses will always return true. What you probably wanted here was `==` and `eq`, not `=`.

You also open two filehandles on the input file, and use the CSV module in the wrong way. I'm not convinced that these minor errors should cause the script to be too slow, but it would be printing all the records in that 5gb file.

Here's a revised version of your script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use autodie;

my $Finput = $ARGV[0];
my $Foutput = $ARGV[1];

open my $FH, "<", $Finput;
open my $out, ">", $Foutput;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

while (my $row = $csv->getline($FH)) {
    my @fields = @$row;
    if ($fields[0] == 10000) {
        if ($fields[34] eq 'abcdef') {
            if ($fields[103] == 9999) {
                $csv->print($out, $row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `autodie` pragma will take care of checking the return value from `open` for us (and other things). `use strict; use warnings;` will make our brains hurt less. Oh, and I am using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm), not the _XS version.

Comment: thanks TLP, I drop added the enbeded if statements as I was typing the message so yes, you are correct they were wrong.  The input/output reading/writing is working correctly under my code and not something I am really worried about here.  Can anyone see a solution that speeds up the searching through large files?  I dont see how this answer addresses that, manybe I am missing it?

Comment: @Nemo, this answer simply rewrites the original to be cleaner and more correct. It doesn't address the performance question at all (which IS the question, not "is this a well written Perl program"). The poster even admits that. The other answers actually attempt to address the performance question either via my regex test or the pre-grep result. Whether those are applicable or successful answers depends on the data set and other factors.

Comment: @jpm With your current data, I believe this is as fast as perl gets. As Will pointed out below, you can try to do quick checks first to discard unwanted lines, but it is unlikely to improve the speed much. If performance is an issue, you most likely would benefit from turning to another form of data storage, like SQL.

Comment: This answer would be improved upon by (1) using Text::CSV_XS, and (2) NOT duplicating each and every row within the while loop.  No need to create a copy with `my @fields = @$row`.  That's extra work.  Just operate on `$row->[0]`, and `$row->[34]`, etc.  Dereferencing is a lot cheaper than copying an array.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use grep "{searchstring}" filename1.csv filename2.csv > savefile.txt on each file. Maybe you want to read the filename.csv line-by-line:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<filename.csv
while read haystack <&3
do
  grep "{needle}" $haystack > result.txt 
done
```

Comment: grep or egrep can work but is there a way to build those commands and ensure that I get a hit when it finds 9999 at position 103 of the csv line and not somewhere else (like 50)?